# Unterschied zwischen "zweifeln", "anzweifeln" und "bezweifeln"?

Tags: meaning

Ich wüsste gern den Unterschied zwischen den Verben: an etw. zweifeln, etw. anzweifeln und etw. bezweifeln.

Vielen Dank

Answer (score 0):

They all mean "to doubt", but they take a prepositional clause, a nominal object and a clausal object, respectively. You should get a dictionary with valence information, they're invaluable when learning idiomatic German.